# golang - antlr - char_stream.go does not implement FromFileName

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

FileStream is deprecated in favor of CharStream,
But in the Go runtime using CharStream.FromFileName(...) results in

```
antlr.CharStream.FromFileName undefined (type "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr".CharStream has no field or method FromFileName)
```

Checking the source I can see the [char_stream.go](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Go/antlr/char_stream.go) does not implement/expose the FromFileName method...

While using NewFileStream(...) results in

```
cannot use file (variable of type *"github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr".FileStream) as type "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4".CharStream in argument to NewralfLexer:
```

What is the correct way to read in a file in this case?

Comment: Use [NewFileStream](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/aa1f1f12a846846fcb78544bdb2ad135471376db/runtime/Go/antlr/v4/file_stream.go#L22) in 4.11.1. Make sure to use the "v4" version!

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose an error from the compiler without actually seeing the source code. Please package it up and attach (preferred) or show your driver code in your question.

Comment: `cannot use file (variable of type *"github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr".FileStream) as type "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4".CharStream in argument to NewralfLexer:` Your program is doing "import" of both "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr" and "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4" in one or more files. Look in every .go file and make sure you are doing an "import" of only "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4", never "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr". Check the generated files as well.

Comment: Thanks That helped me to rootcause the issue.